# Outlook 2007: how to add e-mail in table view to selection without the mouse?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, selection

In `Microsoft Outlook 2007` I often select multiple e-mail messages in the tabular view (e. g. in the Inbox) to process them with a menu command or macro.

Quite often, this is a selection of multiple items, so for example in a list of 5 messages, I only do want to select message 1-3 and 5.

I can extend the selection with `Shift-Downarrow`, but for example if messages 1 and 2 in a list of 5 are already selected and I now want to add the 4th e-mail, how could I do that (without using the mouse)?

Problem: Let's assmue, messages 1 and 2 are already selected. If I now move the cursor to message 4, I loose the selection and only message 4 is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the current focus with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd>/<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to retain the selection intact. After that press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to select/deselect items without loosing the selection.